# How do you make a non-root user use openconnect?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, vpn, openvpn, access-control

Openconnect website does have a chapter called ["Running as a non-root user"](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/nonroot.html).

However, if you read it more closely, you will see that it does not answer the question of how to run `openconnect` as a non-root user. You ether need to call `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script` as a root, or you need to use `ip` tools, which also require root access. In other words, you'll need root access one way and the other.

However, there are legit use cases when we need to grant a user the ability to connect to a VPN, while we still don't want them to have full root access.

How do you cope with that?

Comment: openconnect has a NetworkManager (which is tagged in this question) agent. Can you use NetworkManager without being root? If the answer is yes, that's it.

Comment: I believe that might be a solution, but I'm yet to find a working `.nmconnection` file for a CISCO Anyconnect client. `man nm-settings-keyfile(5)` not very helpful as relevant examples are lacking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unspecific answer, but you can configure tools like 'sudo' to give specific users the ability to run specific commands or script with specifically changed permissions. So you could allow a user sudo permissions to run openconnect and no other command with sudo.

Words of warning, giving a user sudo permissions to run `ip` is unsave. It can be used to gain a general root shell as explained in the [gtfobins](https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/ip/#sudo).

Comment: Good point. Listing commands with `sudo` access is both _unsafe_ and nonpractical here. The former is due to what you referred to. The latter is because `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script` invokes multiple other commands, and exploring the source code of a script to extract the list of programs you should "whitelist" in the `/etc/sudoers` file is not a practical solution.

Comment: As far as I understand you don't need to whitelist all the commands in the script, you just need to whitelist the script. As long as the script is not editable to the user and you can't supply arguments to the script to do things, they are not supposed to do, AND the user can not change the binaries called from the script, it should be save. This is always scary, but it is how access control works and I don't know how it could be improved.

Comment: What useful script do you know to which you cannot supply arguments. For example, `ip` is not save (even has `-batch` flag through which you can supply any script). It's very unsave. See https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/ip/#sudo

Comment: You don't need to know a script you can just write one yourself. And my answer already linked that method.

Comment: Oh, you're right. But, we're talking about `openconnect` here. "whitelisting" `openconnect` does not work.

Comment: I understand, that my answer unspecific, it does not deal with openconnect at all. But I don't understand why it would not work.

Comment: Well, there are many reasons. For example, if you do `sudo openconnect -b ...` your process will be owned by `root` not your user. That is, you'll not be able to do `pkill openconnect`, for example. On the other hand, if you now "whitelist" `kill`, the user will be able to kill any process, and so on ...